# How exactly does JMH do the calculations?Where in the code or in which file can you see the process and formula for calculating "score" and "error"?

Tags: java, java-8, benchmarking, jmh

How exactly does JMH do the calculations? Where in the code or in which file can you see the process and formula for calculating "score" and "error"?

````
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testAdd       avgt    5  223968,116 ± 553800,476  us/op
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testAddAt     avgt    5     198,910 ±     98,401  us/op
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testContains  avgt    5      14,969 ±      1,080  us/op
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testGet       avgt    5       0,004 ±      0,001  us/op
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testIndexOf   avgt    5      20,646 ±      3,313  us/op
CopyOnWriteBenchmark.testRemove    avgt    5      16,443 ±      2,015  us/op```
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking into debugger I see that the code responsible for calculations is generated at compilation time separately for each benchmark. Below there is an example of generated method:

```java
public static void dto_avgt_jmhStub(InfraControl control, RawResults result, BenchmarkParams benchmarkParams, IterationParams iterationParams, ThreadParams threadParams, Blackhole blackhole, Control notifyControl, int startRndMask, ProjectionVsDtoBenchmark_jmhType l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0) throws Throwable {
    long operations = 0;
    long realTime = 0;
    result.startTime = System.nanoTime();
    do {
        blackhole.consume(l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0.dto());
        operations++;
    } while(!control.isDone);
    result.stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    result.realTime = realTime;
    result.measuredOps = operations;
}
```

Here `l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0.dto()` is the method annotated with `@Benchmark`.
The method above is in turn called from this one:

```java
public BenchmarkTaskResult dto_AverageTime(InfraControl control, ThreadParams threadParams) throws Throwable {
    this.benchmarkParams = control.benchmarkParams;
    this.iterationParams = control.iterationParams;
    this.threadParams    = threadParams;
    this.notifyControl   = control.notifyControl;
    if (this.blackhole == null) {
        this.blackhole = new Blackhole("Today's password is swordfish. I understand instantiating Blackholes directly is dangerous.");
    }
    if (threadParams.getSubgroupIndex() == 0) {
        RawResults res = new RawResults();
        ProjectionVsDtoBenchmark_jmhType l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0 = _jmh_tryInit_f_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0(control);

        control.preSetup();


        control.announceWarmupReady();
        while (control.warmupShouldWait) {
            blackhole.consume(l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0.dto());
            res.allOps++;
        }

        notifyControl.startMeasurement = true;
        dto_avgt_jmhStub(control, res, benchmarkParams, iterationParams, threadParams, blackhole, notifyControl, startRndMask, l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0);
        notifyControl.stopMeasurement = true;
        control.announceWarmdownReady();
        try {
            while (control.warmdownShouldWait) {
                blackhole.consume(l_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0.dto());
                res.allOps++;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (!(e instanceof InterruptedException)) throw e;
        }
        control.preTearDown();

        if (control.isLastIteration()) {
            f_projectionvsdtobenchmark0_0 = null;
        }
        res.allOps += res.measuredOps;
        int batchSize = iterationParams.getBatchSize();
        int opsPerInv = benchmarkParams.getOpsPerInvocation();
        res.allOps *= opsPerInv;
        res.allOps /= batchSize;
        res.measuredOps *= opsPerInv;
        res.measuredOps /= batchSize;
        BenchmarkTaskResult results = new BenchmarkTaskResult((long)res.allOps, (long)res.measuredOps);
        results.add(new AverageTimeResult(ResultRole.PRIMARY, "dto", res.measuredOps, res.getTime(), benchmarkParams.getTimeUnit()));
        this.blackhole.evaporate("Yes, I am Stephen Hawking, and know a thing or two about black holes.");
        return results;
    } else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Harness failed to distribute threads among groups properly");
}
```

The results are collected into `BenchmarkTaskResult`, which in turn contains collection of `Result` objects, in this case `AverageTimeResult` containing `Statistics` field.